# Como pegar outro dado ao invés da String que foi clicada no ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma lista de países do tipo ListView, e quando clico no Brasil eu pego a String "Brasil" com o "getItem(position)" mas em vez disso eu gostaria de pegar outro dado, no caso o "BR"que está no banco de dados. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como pegá-lo?
Obs: Estou pegando todos os dados do banco e usando queries para extrair resultados. 
Segue o código que estou usando:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String stringPaises = adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("stringPaises", stringPaises);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);

}
```

Comment: Como é o seu *adapter*?

Comment: Uma maneira é você fazer uma busca no banco de dados passando a stringPaises

Comment: Coloca seu adapter e mostra como você está indo até o banco lá dentro

Comment: Meu adapter recebe uma String do banco e forma a listView. No caso da minha pergunta estou usando a String "Brasil" como parâmetro para retornar uma qwery com a lista dos estados do Brasil que seria usado em outra listView, o que eu queria era usar  a String "BR" em vez de usar a String "Brasil" como parâmetro na qwery. a "BR" está no banco. Eu poderia usar o parâmetro "Brasil" para buscar essa qwery "BR" mas daí eu acho q ficaria meio porco, daí eu  perguntei aqui para saber se existe uma forma mais otimizada.

Comment: O seu *adapter* é um *CursorAdapter*?

Comment: Não. Eu usei um vetor de String para fazer este trabalho, meu adapter é do básico mesmo.

Comment: Pense em usar um, assim poderá aceder mais facilmente ao dados(do BD) referentes à linha que clicou.

Comment: bom, vou tentar, mas obrigado cara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte, crie a seguinte classe:

```
Pais{
   String nome;
   String regiao;

    //gets e sets aqui

   public String toString(){
       return nome;
   }
}
```

no adapter faça:

```
//pega do banco um Pais[] paises;
new ArrayAdapter(context, layout, paises)
```

Ao invés de popular um array de Strings, crie um array de Pais obtidos do banco, e ao invés de passar o array de String no Adapter, passe esse array de Pais.

O que acontece, o Adapter vai mostrar na tela o que retornar no toString()
e o getItem(position) vai retornar o Pais ai é só chamar o objeto.getRegiao() por exemplo.